# How to print from specific column range?

Tags: ruby

I want to grab only the first line of columns 46 to 245 of source.txt and write it to output.txt

```
source_file.each { |line| 
File.open(output_file,"a+") { |f|
    f.print ???
}
```

**Bonus**: I also need to keep a count of the number of characters in this range, as some may be whitespace. i.e. 38 characters and the rest whitespace.

**Example**:

```
source_file: (first line only, columns 45 to 245): 13287912721981239854 + 180 blank columns
output_file: 13287912721981239854   
count = 20 characters
```

**Update**: appending `[46..245].delete(' ').size` gives me the desired count.

Comment: if i open source.txt in notepad and hit the right arrow key 46 times then I am in column 46 and such.. hope that helps..

Comment: This is confusing and I think it's because it isn't written well. Do you want to output columns 46 to 245 of the first line only? What do you mean by your "Bonus:" and wanting to keep a count of the number of characters? You haven't explained your question well, and perhaps providing example input data and your expected output would clarify things nicely.

Comment: @theTinMan An example has been added. Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks. Your code is good, only need the count now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write:

```
source_file.each { |line| 
  File.open(output_file,"a+") { |f|
    f.print ???
  }
}
```

You will open, then close, your output file for each line read from the output file. That is the wrong way to do it, even if you only want to read one line of input.

Instead try something like one of these:

```
File.open(output_file, 'a') do |fo|
  File.open('path/to/input_file') do |fi|
    fo.puts fi.readline[46..245]
  end
end
```

This uses `IO.readline`, which reads a single line from the file. The block falls through afterwards, causing both the input and output files to be closed automatically. Also, it opens the output file as `'a'` which is append-mode only. `'a+'` is wrong unless you intend to append and read, which is rarely done. From [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-open):

```
"a+" Read-write, starts at end of file if file exists,
    otherwise creates a new file for reading and
    writing
```

Or:

```
File.open(output_file, 'a') do |fo|
  File.foreach('path/to/input_file') do |li|
    fo.puts li[46..245]
    break
  end
end
```

[`foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) is used most often when we're reading a file line-by-line. It's the mainstay for reading files in a scalable manner. It wants to loop over the file inside the block, which is why `break` is there, to break out of that loop.

Or:

```
File.foreach('path/to/input_file') do |li|
  File.write(output_file, li[46..245], -1, :mode => 'a')
  break
end
```

[`File.write`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-write) is useful when you have a blob of text or binary, and want to write it in one chunk, then move on. The `-1` tells Ruby to move to the end of the file. `:mode => 'a'` overrides the default mode which would normally truncate an existing file.

Answer (score 3):

If I am understanding what you are asking correctly, there's no reason to grab the whole file when you only want the first line. If this isn't what you're asking for, then you need to specify what you're trying to pull out of the source file more clearly.

This should grab the data you need:

```
output_line = source_file.gets [45..244]
```

Comment: Do something like:
`File.open(output_file, "a+"){|f| f.print source_file.gets [45..244]}`

Comment: Thanks! Can you add the bonus info too? I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will do the job:

```
line = f.readline
columns = line.split
File.open("output.txt", "w") do |out|
  columns[46, (245 - 46 + 1)].each do |column|
    out.puts column
  end
end
break # only process first line
```

I have used `245 - 46 + 1` to indicate this is the number of columns we are interested in. I have also assumed that columns are separate by whitespaces. If that is not the case you will need to change the delimiter of split.

Comment: @JanDvorak this loop is only executed once. Note the break.

Comment: @Bruno well then change the delimiter of split accordingly

Comment: The OP is using `'a+'` for the output file's mode, to append. You're using `'w'`, which would truncate the output file and overwrite it.